# How do shockwaves interact?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics, non-linear-systems, shock-waves

[image]

As seen here, there are two T-38's going supersonic. What happens when those shockwaves interact? They seem to dissipate in some places on this photo when they interact. Any source online says that they will "produce complex patterns of compression, rarefaction, and reflection."

However I can't find anything on *why* that happens.

It also really confuses me how shockwaves can reflect themselves.

Comment: Probably depends on angles of incidences, whether it's head-on or some side-ways collision, strength of the two shocks, etc.

Comment: Linear waves travel through each other without interacting. If they reflect, something must be nonlinear.

Answer (score 1):

Shock waves are still (sound) waves and one would expect things like reflection and refraction.

In reflection and refraction, we need media with varying characteristics (e.g., light through water, we consider the difference in index of refraction to quantify these). In the study of sound waves, a relevant quantity is [acoustic impedance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_impedance), $Z$ where reflection and refraction occur where there is a difference in $Z$ between two regions, and the bigger the difference the more pronounced the reflection and refraction will be.

To see this, note that the reflection coefficient is given by $$R=\frac{Z_1-Z_2}{Z_1+Z_2}$$

and that impedance $$Z= \rho v$$ where $\rho$ is the density of the medium and $v$ the speed of sound.

In other words, if shock waves in air occur across regions of highly differing density, we would expect to see a lot of reflection and refraction. It may also be that due to the nature of shock waves, specifically how the density changes abruptly across it's front and surroundings, this will also lead to reflection and refraction across an air-air interface.

To answer your question directly, reflection and refraction occur across two regions due to differences in pressure/density.

Comment: Oh okay, so do the physics of light refraction apply to shockwaves?

Comment: They are still waves so we would expect wave behavior.